# fatal: unable to connect a socket (No error)

Tags: git

i'm trying to clone a git repo. in ubuntu to local dir in windows with git extensions
when i try to clone, i get these errors:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe clone -v --progress "git://192.168.32.121:gitosis-admin.git" "c:/htdoc/gitosis-admin"
Done
Cloning into c:/htdoc/gitosis-admin...
[0: 192.168.56.1]: errno=No error
[0: 192.168.32.117]: errno=No error
fatal: unable to connect a socket (No error)

the ubuntu is in a virtual box (192.168.32.1) and the windows is 192.168.32.117

i found out the 192.168.56.1 is from my virtual box network card.
can you help me how to solve this?

Greetings,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use gitolite instead of gitosis.

You must have the proper ssh keys in place. See the documentation page for gitolite. It's similar to the gitosis one.

You also must have ssh enabled on your ubuntu vm - it's not there by default. Test it by doing

```
ssh ubuntuip
```

Hope this helps